# Extract values from a dataframe based on a range of values from another dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to extract the index values from a dataframe (`df1`) that represent a range of times (start - end) and that encompass the times given in another dataframe (`df2`). My required output is `df3`.

```
df1<-data.frame(index=c(1,2,3,4),start=c(5,10,15,20),end=c(10,15,20,25))
df2<-data.frame(time=c(11,17,18,5,5,22))
df3<-data.frame(time=c(11,17,18,5,5,22),index=c(2,3,3,1,1,4))
```

Is there a tidyverse solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with R base functions. A combination of `which` inside `sapply` and logical comparison will do the work for you.

```
 inds <- apply(df1[,-1], 1, function(x) seq(from=x[1], to=x[2]))
 index <- sapply(df2$time, function(x){
   tmp <- which(x == inds, arr.ind = TRUE);
   tmp[, "col"]
 } )
 df3 <- data.frame(df2, index)
 df3
  time index
1   11     2
2   17     3
3   18     3
4    5     1
5    5     1
6    8     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
df1<-data.frame(index=c(1,2,3,4),start=c(5,10,15,20),end=c(10,15,20,25))
df2<-data.frame(time=c(11,17,18,2,5,5,8,22))
```

Code:

```
# get index values and assign it to df2 column
df2$index <- apply( df2, 1, function(x) { with(df1, index[ x[ 'time' ]  >= start & x[ 'time' ] <= end ] ) })
```

Output:

```
df2
#   time index
# 1   11     2
# 2   17     3
# 3   18     3
# 4    2      
# 5    5     1
# 6    5     1
# 7    8     1
# 8   22     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `findInterval`

```
ftx <- function(x, y) findInterval(x, y)
df3 <- transform(df2, index = pmax(ftx(time, df1$start), ftx(time, df1$end)))

df3
#   time index
#1   11     2
#2   17     3
#3   18     3
#4    5     1
#5    5     1
#6   22     4
```

---

Or another option is `foverlaps` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dfN <- data.table(index = seq_len(nrow(df2)), start = df2$time, end = df2$time)
setDT(df1)
setkey(dfN, start, end)
setkey(df1, start, end)
foverlaps(dfN, df1, which = TRUE)[, yid[match(xid, dfN$index)]]
#[1] 2 3 3 1 1 4
```

---

As the OP commented about using a solution with pipes, @Jilber Urbina's solution can be implemented with `tidyverse` functions

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    select(from = start, to = end) %>% 
    pmap(seq) %>% 
    do.call(cbind, .) %>% 
    list(.) %>%
    mutate(df2, new = ., 
                ind = map2(time, new, ~ which(.x == .y, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])) %>%
    select(-new)
#   time ind
#1   11   2
#2   17   3
#3   18   3
#4    5   1
#5    5   1
#6   22   4
```

Comment: Thanks for all these potential solutions. I may be on the wrong track here but the reason that I asked for tidyverse solution was because in my actual data I have different groups so was hoping to use the group_by function. After trying all of these solutions in loops iterating over the grouped variable and outputing in a list I get a mix of vectors ant lists within the original list which is really frustrating. Is there anyway to include agrouped variable in any of the above?

Comment: @AlMac  You can implement JilberUrbina's method in a chain i.e. `df1 %>% select(from = start, to = end) %>% pmap(seq) %>% do.call(cbind, .)  %>% list(.) %>% mutate(df2, new = ., ind = map2(time, new, ~ which(.x == .y, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]))  %>% select(-new)`

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this but get the following error:

Comment: Error in select(., from = start, to = end) : 
  unused arguments (from = start, to = end)

Comment: @AlMac  I am using the same dataset as in your post.  What is your package version for dplyr?  I use `dplyr_0.7.4`

Comment: akrun - I am using the same version as you - do you think it may be a a conflict with tidyverse?

Comment: @AlMac  It could be the case.  I am loading packages individually instead of the tidyverse package. i.e. `library(dplyr);library(purrr);library(tidyr)`  Can you try `dply::select(from = start, to = end)`

Comment: @AlMac  Some functions are found in multiple packages, so there is chance of it getting masked.  Can you try `dplyr::select(from = start, to = end)` to make it known that the function is from dplyr

Comment: OK thanks this worked but I am going to repost a question with the grouped variable using the code you provided as a baseline as I like your pipe method